# Changing registry values in AutoIt does not work

Tags: windows, scripting, registry, autoit, regedit

I'm trying to change some registry settings using an AutoIt script. The regWrite() method returns 1, which means that it was successful and when I call RegRead() on the same key it gives me the value that I passed into RegWrite(), but the value in does not change in regedit, even if I reboot the computer. I tried it on more than 10 keys and none of them really changed.

Sample code:

This is just one of the values I tried to change:

```
#RequireAdmin

RegWrite("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESET\Setup\CurrentSession","RebootSignal","REG_DWORD","0x00000000")
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
RegWrite("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESET\Setup\CurrentSession","RebootSignal","REG_DWORD",0x00000000)
```

or

```
RegWrite("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESET\Setup\CurrentSession","RebootSignal","REG_DWORD",0)
```

Comment: What is the difference? @Milos

Comment: The missing double quotes around the last parameter... ;-)

Comment: You are writing a string to the registry when there should be a numeric value.